# Unable to fetch dynamically added text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue with my jQuery code. I am unable to access the dynamically added element. I can access it if I refresh the page.

I am working on a jQuery/HTML5 todo list application. In [my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/44/), if you add an item and hit "mark as Done" (after hovering on the numbered button), the item is removed from the UI but not from the localStorage. The code is not able to locate the task content (JS line # 180).

```
var remove_item_text = $(element).next().text();    // not fetching the text
```

It goes as blank and it is not actually removed from the localStorage. If you refresh the page, the item shows up again. And now if you hit "mark as Done", the element is removed from the localStorage. Isnt that weird?

What am I missing here?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/csTS7/44/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that new added item is not wrapped into `<p class='item_content'>` tag. Hence `.next()` can't get this element and can't get its text (next considers element nodes and skips text nodes).

So to fix it you should append a new item inside `addItem` method like this:

```
$("ul").append("<li class='ui-state-default'><button class='done'>Done</button>"+
               "<p class='item_content'>" + $("#new_todo_item").val() + "</p>" +
               "<input type='checkbox' class='star' "+checked+" />"+
               "<label for='star'>Star</label>");
```

(the same as in `checkLocalStorageExistingData` method).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/csTS7/46/

Comment: My bad! Its always that little thing. :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/csTS7/50/ You have to unbind event before binding new handlers.